# Lower case object values in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in typescript to specify that this function will return an object and object values will be a lower case?

This is what I have for now:

```
const lowercaseObjValues = <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  obj: T
) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc: T, key: string) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key].toLowerCase();
    return acc;
  }, {} as T);
};
```

Comment: A string is a string, doesn't matter if it is upperCase or LowerCase, that kind of info is irrelevant for typing

Comment: @VítorFrança Typescript has string literal types, and it’s extremely powerful. So one could easily have a type of `'FOO'` and want to convert that to a type of `'foo'`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of function will only really be helpful if the string values are statically known.

```js
// helper function to add types to Object.entries
const entries = Object.entries as <T>(obj: T) => [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];

type LowercaseValues<T extends Record<string, string>> = { [K in keyof T]: Lowercase<T[K]> };

const lowercaseValues = <T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T): LowercaseValues<T> =>
  entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    // i'm sure this explicit `any` can be removed but it can be left as an
    // exercise for the reader
    acc[key] = value.toLowerCase() as any;
    return acc;
  }, {} as LowercaseValues<T>);

const test = { a: 'UPPER' } as const;
const out = lowercaseValues(test);

declare const assert: <T>(a: T) => void;

assert<'UPPER'>(test.a);
assert<'upper'>(out.a);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAlnCMC8MDyAjAKzmCgDoFk0MBDDAHgBUA+AChEIC4YGBKLJmAG0A1nACeIAGbcANNxHip3ALrLBygFAaoYgA5wYAGRAB3OEmC04ANWoAbAK7pG8AB5QEAEwwAlYiCRPOmhUMABzORCUcKYBbABvIQBpGGiYUQlpBmUuYzMLK0ZBJOUBAF8Abi1QSFg7U3NLCBt7JwxsFzh3L19-QODKcMjBsNi2Tm4eXIaC5ttHZ2Z+eERUdHGCHg0YGFIkOE8HYDgWFmpgYDkFMTkAN1a4ZT5MAXjtnZhz4GvlLBh7hakKAgPLmADCVhYfFonzAYiqHxg+ygDiQYE+FwRMDKcniZU+GFBsxaCwgjCYWw0NWgMA8NIS1C4AHIAKoABTZAFEfEz8TDqVAqlTwDSQA5YNh6vkmiS2iw6VAeELPMQ7NR9jABQTmkgoFxyWcuLxlrcQChPELaDqoHRWRzuUzWArSNQlRoreYbUyHLp9EhHWxxS63RogA)